# Nooby Android Developer

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation

so I just recently (yesterday) started developing on the Android platform. So far I have created a Hello World application as described in their tutorial, but it does not run. When I run it, it waits at the blinky Android screen, then finally moves to the screen where it says Android in a fancy font and its kind of glossy and silver but never moves from there. What have I done wrong? Thank you.

Comment: how old is your machine ? Sometimes it takes a very long time to launch the emulator.

Comment: I agree with Thomas, it takes FOREVER for the Emulator to start the first time.  Try just letting it run.

Comment: Actually, I just had this happen to me.. it hung during startup for many many minutes -- whether it was related to my horribly loaded system at the time, I have no idea. Restarting it sorted things.

Comment: use a virtual device
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 2):

That just sounds like the Android emulator isn't starting properly.

If you run `adb logcat` from the command line, or open "LogCat" view in Eclipse, do you see any messages appearing?  You may have to select the "emulator-5554" device first from the "Devices" tab first.

Answer (score 1):

Try exiting the emulator and eclipse both, and then restarting eclipse and running the project once again. This worked for me.